# Is the Mendeleev table explained in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry, atoms

Does anybody know if there exists a mathematical explanation of Mendeleev table in quantum mechanics? In some textbooks (for example in [F.A.Berezin, M.A.Shubin. The Schrödinger Equation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/079231218X)) the authors present quantum mechanics as an axiomatic system, so one could expect that there is a deduction from the axioms to the main results of the discipline. I wonder if there is a mathematical proof of the Mendeleev table?

Comment: How do you define the Mendeleev table? i.e. what propositions do you want to see derived?

Comment: Cross-posted from http://mathoverflow.net/q/80146/13917

Comment: What you call Mendeleev table physicist know it as the periodic table of elements ( first published by Mendeleev) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table . This is a table of data. Data know nothing about axioms and theoretical proofs. The job of theoretical physicists is to find a self consistent theory ( which should have axioms and proofs) which offers solutions that can fit the data. This theory exists and it is quantum mechanics. Special solutions from this theory can fit the periodic table well. When physicists say that they fit the data well, they always give an error margin.

Comment: This error margin knows nothing about theorems and axioms, but depends on measurement and systematic errors. There cannot be a mathematical proof of data. There can only be a fit of a solution from a mathematical theory to the data, and this is done within the error margins of the data.

Comment: To put it another way, mathematics cannot prove that hydrogen exists, nor its energy levels. What mathematics can do is develop a theory that can give solutions that can fit the data. In physics, mathematics is a tool that is used to fit how  Nature (Physis in ancient greek) behaves, allowing for predictions of new phenomena.

Comment: Major edits rolled back. This is not a discussion forum, nor it is a platform for your epistemological arguments. We do *science* here, not pure math. Formal proofs take a back seat to correct predictions and agreement with reality. I understand that you wanted this to be on a math site, but it *is* on a physics site.

Comment: To expand on (or clarify) what dmckee said: this is a site for questions. A question post should ask the question, and that's all. The material that dmckee edited out (mostly?) does not belong as part of this post, but it would go quite well on [chat] if anyone else is interested in having that discussion.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, quantum mechanics – even non-relativistic quantum mechanics for several electrons orbiting nuclei – fully, quantitatively, and comprehensively explains all of chemistry (including biochemistry and, in fact, biology). This fact has been known since the late 1920s.

To understand the periodic character of the properties of the elements, one must realize that already the Hydrogen atom has energy eigenstates given by quantum numbers $(n,l,m)$ as well as the binary $s_z$. Energy as well as degeneracy increases as a function of $n$. When many electrons are allowed (to neutralize the positive electric charge of the nucleus), the Pauli principle (coming from the antisymmetry of the electrons' wave functions, a fact that may be deduced from quantum field theory but may be assumed as another axiom of the simplified quantum mechanical model) says that the electrons will gradually fill the states with the ever higher values of $n$. Every time one fills all states with $n<n_0$ up to some $n_0$, one gets inert gases. When one more electron is added to the new shell, we get highly reactive elements (because they include one loosely bound electron in the outer shell), and so on.

The only variation one has to add to make the calculation of the atomic energy levels exact are the electron-electron interactions (if there are at least two electrons). They slightly reorder the shells that are being filled, $1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d$, and so on... The problem (aside from the basic Hydrogen problem) obviously can't be solved analytically but there exist lots of numerical techniques to find the right results and everything that has been calculated - and some of the calculations were very precise - agrees with the observations. The calculations become more complex for larger atoms (or molecules), of course. But when the size is large enough, one may use new simplifying assumptions or approximations so it's not necessary the case that it's always harder to understand/calculate larger objects.

Comment: Dear DrSAR, the answer to your question is No, there is no joke or irony, neither intended nor unintended, in my answer. It was a well-defined question whether a subset of physics describes some class of observations and the answer is obviously Yes. I think it's good that this question was asked because people - and not only those who love to visit witches to predict the future etc. - often associate elementary low-energy physics such as atomic physics with lots of mystery that doesn't exist. All these things are almost perfectly understood.

Comment: Given the [answer below](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24589), it would be better to include a proof that the answer to"there is a mathematical proof of the Mendeleev table" is yes. This could be done by pointing to any evidence that this has been done. In other words, the question is not asking whether it's doable in line of principle, but whether it's *done*. Big difference.

Comment: @Sklivvz: if, as you say, it's done, then it is you who should give a reference, the OP is not obliged to divine your hints, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I am not saying its done. I agree its doable in principle, but it's not done afaik. The calculations are still too complex.

Comment: @Sklivvz: excuse me, your first comment had been changed a little bit. Just yesterday it was the following:

<<Given the answer below, I would like to challenge the OP to prove that the answer to "there is a mathematical proof of the Mendeleev table" is yes. This could be done by pointing to any evidence that this has been done. In other words, the question is not asking whether it's doable in line of principle, but whether it's done. Big difference. – Sklivvz♦ Dec 26 '12 at 1:18>>

What could this modification mean? :)

Comment: You know it's difficult to follow the thought of the interlocutor, when he makes corrections in his old statements all the way. If you didn't mean that it's done, then I do not understand what you wanted to say. How can you be sure (and how do you expect me to agree) that this is doable, of this is not done? Wouldn't it be more clever to wait until this will be done, before making such risky declarations? And what was your challenge to the OP? -- that is the puzzle now.

Comment: I am not the one asserting that statement. I am asserting that whomever says is doable, should provide proof - so basically I am agreeing with you. I don't expect you to agree that it's doable without proof. I am asserting that Lubos needs to provide proof that it's doable before asserting what he says. While I can speculate that it's very likely that QM can explain away chemistry eventually, it clearly doesn't do that if the calculations are unfeasible.

Comment: Sorry about the ninja change. I simply rectified the tone.

Comment: @Sklivvz: OK. So as I understand, we have no controversy. And you are a moderator, is it? Then I believe, you can explain another ninja change: who and why deleted the chain of comments after my answer here?

Comment: @Sklivvz: And I believe you can explain to whom I should address this: <<P.S. To moderators or people who are responsible for the moderation: I am the very same Sergei Akbarov, who initially posted this question at theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com in November 2011. Is it possible to identify me here as an author?>> I want to add something right in the text of the question. Something clever.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I am a Stack Exchange developer, not a mod, but I do have mod powers. The comments were removed by a community moderator. I do not know explicitly why he did that.

Comment: "The comments were removed by a community moderator." What is his name? I'd like to contact him.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov David Z.

Comment: David Zaslavsky?

Comment: Dear @Sklivvz, I didn't just write that it's "doable". I wrote the sketch of the actual proof. Just to remind you, the OP asked whether the periodic table of elements is explained by quantum mechanics. The answer is an unequivocal Yes. I really wrote the explanation to remind those who have thought about this important aspect of modern science. The arrangement of the elements into groups with similar properties, and which Z are in the same group with other Z, is surely explained by QM. In fact, QM has correctly calculated much more quantitative, accurate, detailed data.

Answer (score 17):

While quantum mechanics explains the gross features of the periodic system, many fine details of the periodic table of elements are computable numerically from various approximations to QED, but are conceptually ill understood. See, e.g.,

> Eric R. Scerri, How Good Is the Quantum Mechanical Explanation of the Periodic System? [*J. Chem. Educ.* **75**, 1384 (1998)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed075p1384).

Scerri also wrote a book on the subject (*The periodic table: its story and its significance*, 2007). Several book reviews are available online:

- [Werner Kutzelnigg](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qua.22276/abstract) writes in his review: ''I am personally skeptical 
  whether a genuine PS [periodic system] of the elements that 
  incorporates all chemical properties of the elements (e.g., their 
  tendency to form covalent, ionic, semipolar, multicenter, or 
  hypervalent bonds) will ever be formulated. Another issue about which 
  one would like to learn more is whether the periodic system has a 
  chance to survive in the realm of superheavy elements.''
- [Michael Laing](http://www.platinummetalsreview.com/pdf/207-266-pmr-oct08.pdf#page=43) describes (for the Platinum Metals review) in his 
  review anomalies of platinum.

It is difficult to derive from the periodic table (or from quantum 
mechanics) precise, **generally** valid laws about chemical elements.
In a 2008 paper for *American Scientist* ([**96** no. 1, 52-58 (2008)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1511/2008.69.52)), [The past and future of the periodic table](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263442539_The_Past_and_Future_of_the_Periodic_Table), 
Scerri writes about the predictive power of the periodic system,

> if one considers all of Mendeleev's many predictions 
>   of new elements, his powers of prophecy appear somewhat less 
>   impressive, even to the point of being a little worrying. In all 
>   Mendeleev predicted a total of 18 elements, of which only nine were 
>   subsequently isolated. [...] the Davy medal, which predates the Nobel 
>   Prize as the highest accolade in chemistry, was jointly awarded to 
>   Mendeleev and Julius Lothar Meyer, his leading competitor, who did not 
>   make any predictions. Indeed, there is not even a mention of 
>   Mendeleev's predictions in the published speech that accompanied the 
>   joint award of the Davy prize. It therefore seems that this prize was 
>   awarded for the manner in which the two chemists has successfully 
>   accommodated the then-known elements into their respective periodic 
>   systems rather than for any foretelling.
>
> it is possible to predict that subsequent main shells of the atom 
>   can contain a maximum of 2, 8, 18 or 32 electrons. This is in perfect 
>   agreement with the lengths of periods in the chemist's periodic table. 
>   The simple quantum mechanical theory does not, however, account for the 
>   repetition of all period lengths except for the first one. Indeed, 
>   this problem has continued to elude theoretical physicists until quite 
>   recently. Appropriately enough, it was a Russian physicist, the late 
>   Valentin Ostrovsky, who recently published a theory to explain this 
>   feature, although it is not yet generally accepted. Although the theory 
>   is too mathematically complicated to explain here, Ostrovsky's work 
>   and some other competing accounts demonstrate that the periodic table 
>   continues to be an area of active research by physicists as well as 
>   chemists even though it has existed for nearly 140 years.''

For a very recent review on the expert level, see the paper

[The physics behind chemistry, and the Periodic Table](http://www.chem.helsinki.fi/~pyykko/pekka/CR.pdf) by Pekka Pyykkü ([*Chem. Rev.* **112**, 371 (2012)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/cr200042e)).
He mentions that a number of important effects (such as the color of 
gold, the liquidity of mercury, or the voltage of a lead-acid battery) 
need QED (more precisely the Dirac-Coulomb-Breit approximation to QED 
rather than the textbook nonrelativistic Schrödinger equation) for 
their correct explanation. He treats the periodic system shorter than 
the title would suggest, but makes up for this in

[this paper](http://www.chem.helsinki.fi/~pyykko/pekka/PT.pdf) ([*Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.* **13**, 161 (2011)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C0CP01575J)).

Of interest may also be papers by

[Bonchev](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236671879_Periodicity_of_the_Chemical_Elements_and_Nuclides_An_Information_Theoretic_Analysis)
and

[Kibler](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0611287); the latter relates the periodic system to the dynamical 
symmetry group $\rm SO(4,2)$ of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: Why knock on Mendeleev? He had the right idea, and he was heckled enough in his own time. He was many decades ahead of all his competitors, and all his sound predictions were verified, and those that weren't were only because of isotope anomalies that he couldn't have understood back then. You might as well criticize Gell-Mann for not figuring out everything about quarks in 1964.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Stating an interesting fact about his prediction doesn't make his accomplishemnts smaller. Your comment makes sense with the definition of ''sound'' = ''what agreed with reality'', but how would you have told what was sound before the experiments that decided upon agreement with reality?

Comment: This comment is a little naive--- the experimental data sufficient to establish the table was known in the 19th century, as demonstrated by the fact that Mendeleev did it. The further experiments served to seal the coffin on alternate theories, and were political necessities, not logical necessities. The previous experiments were sufficient for the logical development, and the resistance to Mendeleev was ignorant and reactionary, as is the resistance to all new ideas at all times.

Comment: Then why did Mendeleev propose the 9 unsound predictions if it was all known to him? With 9 correct out of 9 predictions he would have been a much better predictor than with 9 correct out of 18, which reveals a lack of good prediction rules based on what he already knew.

Answer (score -2):

From what I learned here and at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80146/is-the-mendeleev-table-explained-in-quantum-mechanics), where this question was originally posted, I deduce that the answer to it is “no”. I.e. *the mathematical proof of the Mendeleev table was  not found by now*. I am sorry to inform you, dear physicists. And this has nothing in common with the nuances you are talking about, in particular with the problem of “superheavy elements”. Even the simpliest properties of elements are formally not explained from the mathematical point of view, since no axiomatic theory was constructed for this (in contrast to some other physical disciplines, like classical mechanics). Those of you, who don’t agree can join the discussion at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80146/is-the-mendeleev-table-explained-in-quantum-mechanics) for explaining your opinion to mathematicians.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65564/discussion-on-answer-by-sergei-akbarov-is-the-mendeleev-table-explained-in-quant).