# Why do nodes exist in wavefuncions of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, orbitals

Nodes are points in space around a nucleus where the probability of finding an electron is zero. However, is there a reason for the existence of Nodes? I'm looking for an intuitive explanation if possible and links to any literature that gives the math behind :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron shells in atoms: What causes them to exist as they do?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129134/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron shells in atoms: What causes them to exist as they do?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129134/)

Comment: Do you understand why there are nodes in a string vibrating in a standing wave?

Comment: There are also the nodes on Chladni plates which may help intuition: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Round_Chladni_plate_with_4_circular_and_2_linear_nodes.JPG

Comment: A deleted answer linked to [this post on Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8655/36303).