# Quantum objects duality between waves and particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, wave-particle-duality

i am reading an intresting book titled "Life on the edge: the coming age of quantum biology".
And the subject of "quantum objects duality between waves and particles" takes a big part of this book.
I was trying to understand how a quantum object like electron can have this duality property, while reading i had an idea which i don't know if it is right, but i wanted to check about it.
It has two points :
1-) from the famous equation of Einstein "E = mc^2" which indicates that matter is just a hight concentration of energy in one place.
2-) in the electromagnetic spectrum high energy radiation has shorter wavelingth, the more energy it has the shorter its wavelength gets.
So the idea is that if you increased the energy of a radiation much enough so that its wavelength reachs zero or near zero value, then you will have a intense concentration of energy in tiny part of space and that is a particle who is actualy a wave with high energy !!??
Does this idea hit any right spots?

Answer (score 0):

> So the idea is that if you increased the energy of a radiation much enough so that its wavelength reachs zero or near zero value, then you will have a intense concentration of energy in tiny part of space and that is a particle who is actualy a wave with high energy !!?? Does this idea hit any right spots?

Not really, because it is a classical picture. [Please read this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476972/discrete-energy-levels-of-electrons-in-isolated-atom/476980#476980) to get a summary of what a quantum mechanical framework is, and why it had to be used.

At very small distances light, your radiation, is seen to be composed out of photons, the elementary particles of light , of energy $hν$ , and mass zero as seen in this [elementary particles table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle), $ν$ is the frequency of the classical light, and  $h$ [Planck's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant), characterizing quantum dimensions.

[Very high frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum) mean very high energy photons, called gamma rays, that is all.

Individual photons leave a footprint of a particle,a point,  [as seen here](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/),on the left frame,  in  a single photon at a time double slit experiment.

[image: sngphot]

[The wave nature of the photon](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) is seen  in the accumulation towards the right, which shows interference patterns, characteristic of waves, and the classical wave which these photons build up.

The wave particle duality in quantum mechanics lies in that : in interacting the footprint is a point, in accumulating a probability distribution for interacting (towards the right) , the wave nature appears, and is modeled by solutions of quantum mechanical wave equations.

The predictions of quantum mechanical equations are probability distributions for finding a particle at an (x,y,z,t).

So your model is not true to nature's solution.